# How to negate class selector in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: class, selector, cytoscape.js, negation

I want to select all elements that do not have the class "myclass". How can I do that in Cytoscape.js?

According to http://js.cytoscape.org/#selectors/data, "`[^name]` Matches elements if the specified data attribute is not defined", however a class is not a data attribute and `^.myclass` does not work, neither does `:not(.myclass)`.

The error is `The selector :not(.myclass) is invalid`.

Is there a way to negate classes?

Comment: The  tags are probably not neccessary, it doesn't hurt, but people who don't know cytoscape probably won't know how selection works.

Comment: Do you want to filter nodes or also edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the negative class selector, you can do this:

```
cy.elements().not(cy.$('.yourClass'));

// in more detail
var allElements = cy.elements(); // get all elements
var negators = cy.$('.yourClass');  // get all elements with the class to negate
var result = allElements.not(negators); // gets the difference between the two collections
```

Comment: I would prefer to have it inside the selector but if that it isn't possible I will use this, thanks!

Comment: `eles.data('isFoo', true)` has the same relative performance as `eles.addClass('foo')`.  If you're using a class for real state (not just visual styling), it probably makes more sense to use a data field.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to achieve this by using selectors only, then you might add a data field to each element which has `myclass` (this can be done while adding the class), and then use `[^myclass]`

Comment: There seems to be no way to set an attribute to a set of elements and I don't want to loop through all of them because of the performance impact.

Comment: `eles.data('isFoo', true)` should set the attribute for all elements. But it will also affect the performance in some ways.